# Output all current buffers

Tags: json, emacs

Is there any extension to Emacs that will emit the contents of all the buffers? I'm especially interested in something that outputs JSON or XML. I would like to build some front-ends for an Emacs session in a browser environment with JavaScript.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "emit" etc. Please try to clarify what you are looking for, so it will be easier to help you.

Comment: You can serve the content directly from Emacs using [elnode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Elnode); then you have *direct* access to the buffers (and everything else), and you don't need to bother with javascript at all.

Comment: [impatient-mode](https://github.com/skeeto/impatient-mode) does something similar, if I understand your correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can find everything you need using `M-x apropos RET buffer RET`.
Some highlights:

- `buffer-list` – gives you the list of open buffers
- `with-current-buffer` – sets a buffer as the current one
- `buffer-string` – the current buffer's content as a string

As for the JSON part, use the `json` package, particularly its `json-encode` function.